# How to handle custom url in android

Tags: android, android-intent, equals, custom-url

I'm trying to handle a custom event generated by me and I'm encountering an error.

My intent is:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="eg" android:host="action" />
```

My activity is:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    String valueOne = uri.getQueryParameter("lat");
    String valueTwo = uri.getQueryParameter("long");
}
```

I am getting error in if condition. 
errors:
cannot resolve the symbol 'equals'
cannot resolve the symbol 'getAction'
I have imported all the necessary header files.

Comment: Please consider reframing your question, the title and the question do not specify what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the following line to import the Intent class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

Comment: Yes I have imported it.